# Differentiate $y= -3x(2-3x^2)^{-1/2} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate

$y= -3x(2-3x^2)^{-1/2} $

I've tried but couldn't get the correct answer ,
Here's my workings -

$ -3x(\frac{-1}{2} (2-3x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} \frac{d}{dx} 2 - \frac{d}{dx} 3x^2) + (2-3x^2)^{-1/2} (-3) $

$= -9x^2(2-3x^2)^{-3/2} - 3(2-3x^2)^{-1/2} $

Then I simplify

$= -3(2-3x^2)^{\frac{-3}{2}} (3x^2 - 2 + 3x^2)$

$= \frac{-3(6x^2-2)}{(2-3x^2)^{3/2}} $

The numerator should be $-6$, but my answer is not correct . Can I know where I have went wrong

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Application of quotient and chain rule simultaniously is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake  is at the first line. Notice

$$\frac{dx^a}{dx} = ax^{a-1}$$

so applying this to your case:

$$\frac{d (2-3x^2)^{-1/2}}{dx} = -\frac{1}{2}(2-3x^2)^{-3/2}(-6x)$$

I will now work out the entire derivative for you:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= (-3x(2-3x^2)^{-1/2})' = -3*(2-3x^2)^{-1/2} - 3x* \frac{(-1)}{2}(2-3x^2)^{-3/2}(-6x)$$

$$= -3(2-3x^2)^{-1/2} - 9x^2(2-3x^2)^{-3/2}$$

$$= \frac{-3}{\sqrt{2-3x^2}} - \frac{9x^2}{\sqrt{2-3x^2}^3}$$

$$= \frac{-3(2-3x^2)}{\sqrt{2-3x^2}^3} - \frac{9x^2}{\sqrt{2-3x^2}^3}$$

$$ = \frac{-6}{\sqrt{2-3x^2}^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

we get
$$y'(x)=-3(2-3x^2)^{-1/2}-3x(-\frac{1}{2})(2-3x^3)^{-3/2}(-6x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick: just square both sides and implicit differentiate:

$$y^2=\frac{9x^2}{2-3x^2} \Rightarrow $$
$$2y\cdot y'=\frac{18x\cdot(2-3x^2)-9x^2\cdot(-6x)}{(2-3x^2)^2}=\frac{
36x}{(2-3x^2)^2} \Rightarrow$$
$$y'=\frac{36x}{2y(2-3x^2)^2}=\frac{36x}{2(-3x)(2-3x^2)^{-1/2}(2-3x^2)^2}=\frac{-6}{(2-3x^2)^{3/2}}$$